# How to Convert 24hour to 12 hour in C#

Tags: c#, time

I am trying to convert time from 24 hours to 12 hours.
The value I receive is: `11:10:00.000Z` I want to convert it to 11:00 am

This is what I am trying to use:

```
time = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
   e.From_Time,
   "HH:mm:ss fffZ", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
).DateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to "convert" anything. This is just a [formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#ttSpecifier) issue.

Comment: BTW, your "conversion" would be wrong unless you _intend_ to drop time resolution to the full hour. If that is the case, it's a one-liner: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eX4reX

Comment: The only issue I see here is the discrepancy between the format you expect and the value you're parsing, but that could be a typo when writing the question. We really need details of the problem, not just the code and the goal.

Comment: ^^ Right, I fixed that in the Fiddle -> `"HH:mm:ss fffZ"` vs `"HH:mm:ss.fffZ"`

Comment: Unrelated: I wrote an answer but I need to make some assumptions to be able to. I should not have to. So, I strongly advise you read [ask] and consider those guidelines in your next question.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, there is one issue in your code, we need to address first:

Your input is "11:10:00.000Z" but your expected format is "HH:mm:ss fffZ".

That won't work. **It needs to be "HH:mm:ss.fffZ"**.
That may or may not have been a typo while writing the question, though.

So, that out of the way, it also *seems* as if you want to drop minutes?

**If that is the case** you can use a formatting like this:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(input, "HH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              .ToString("hh:00 tt");
```

as shown in this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eX4reX).

**If that was a typo, too**, then all you need to do is include the minutes:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(input, "HH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              .ToString("hh:mm tt");
```